# Calculate all possible combinations of symmetries on a 10x10 square grid

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, symmetry, combinatorial-game-theory

I would like to calculate all possible combinations of symmetries, that a $10\times 10$ board of [Dots and Boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes) can have. For this purpose we only care about what lines have been drawn, but not which player owns which box. For example, a $3\times 3$ board might look as follows:

```
o-o o
| |
o-o-o
  | |
o o-o
```

I've looked up the following notation: $\rho_0, \rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3$ for $0$, $90$, $180$ and $270$ counterclockwise rotation; $\mu_1, \mu_2$ for mirroring about vertical and horizontal axis; $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$ for mirroring about top-left-bottom-right and top-right-bottom-left diagonals respectively. 

The example above would therefore have $(\rho_0,\rho_2,\delta_1,\delta_2)$ symmetries.

I wrote a script to generate all $3\times 3$ boards and calculate which combinations of symmetries they have, but I'm not sure whether the result generalizes to $10\times 10$ case, as for example, $2\times 2$ boards have less possible combinations than $3\times 3$. Is there an analytical way to do it?

All possible combinations of symmetries for $3 \times 3$ boards are:
$(\rho_0)$
$(\rho_0,\rho_2)$
$(\rho_0,\mu_1)$
$(\rho_0,\mu_2)$
$(\rho_0,\delta_1)$
$(\rho_0,\delta_2)$
$(\rho_0,\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3)$
$(\rho_0,\rho_2,\mu_1,\mu_2)$
$(\rho_0,\rho_2,\delta_1,\delta_2)$
$(\rho_0,\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3,\mu_1,\mu_2,\delta_1,\delta_2)$

Comment: As soon as the grid is large enough to have an edge that is not itself symmetric (i.e. only $\rho_0$ symmetry), the symmetry operations will turn that one edge into 8 edges. By choosing which subset of those 8 edges to include/exclude in your pattern, your pattern can have any of the symmetry groups you identified.

Comment: You need to account for the symmetry group of the square, usually called $D_4$. This gives you all the symmetries you want. The $2\times 2$ board is special in the sense that not all elements of $D_4$ give distinct transformations.